# Cakephp - HABTM relationship lost after calling method

Tags: cakephp, model, has-and-belongs-to-many

## The Issue

I have two methods I need to call in my getContacts function. These methods are as follows:

**Method 1:**
$authenticated = $this->authenticateUserInternal($inputData['auth']);

**Method 2:**
$result = $this->Consumer->find('first', array( 'conditions' => array('Consumer.id' => 81)));

When I invoke these methods one after the other my resultset in $result does not have data from related tables. It seems like Method 1 is killing the relationship or affecting my results somehow, but it's a completely un-related function in the AppController.

## The Code

The the Consumer model has a HABTM relationship to my Users model through a join table consumers_users.

**Consumer Model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
'User' => array( 'className' => 'User', 'joinTable' => 'consumers_users', 'foreignKey'     => 'consumer_id', 'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id', ));
```

**User Model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
'Consumer' => array(
    'className' => 'Consumer',
    'joinTable' => 'consumers_users',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'consumer_id',
));
```

**ConsumersUsers Model**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
'User' => array( 'className' => 'User', 'foreignKey' => 'user_id', ), 'Consumer' =>        array( 'className' => 'Consumer', 'foreignKey' => 'consumer_id', ), );
```

My normal result

```
"Consumer": {

"id": "81",
"fullname": "consumer2",
"email": "consumer2@cici.mailgun.org",
"password": "111111",
"dateregistered": "2013-08-18",
"audio": "0"
}, "User": [

{
    "id": "179",
    "fullname": "leesa",
    "email": "lda@hotmail.com",
    "password": "111111",
    "imageurl": "http://bridgefiles.s3.amazonaws.com/2013-07-18-144613_IMG_0773.jpeg",
    "thumb_url": "http://bridgefiles.s3.amazonaws.com/2013-07-18-144613_IMG_0773.jpeg",
    "messagecount": "2",
    "dateregistered": "2013-07-29",
    "phone1": null,
    "phone2": null,
    "videoaddress": null,
    "ConsumersUser": {
        "id": "17",
        "consumer_id": "81",
        "status": "accepted",
        "user_id": "179"
    }
},
```

### The Actual Result

```
"Consumer": {

"id": "81",
"fullname": "consumer2",
"email": "consumer2@cici.mailgun.org",
"password": "111111",
"dateregistered": "2013-08-18",
"audio": "0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting only the table consumer, I think that the right way is to load the join table and insert recursive 1 to retrieve both table Consumer and User
try this:

```
$this->loadModel('ConsumersUsers');
 $result = $this->ConsumersUsers->find('first', array( 'conditions' => array('Consumer.id' => 81), 'recursive' => 1));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't do it.  I also noticed that both this and my way resulted in the Column in the conditions not being found.  As soon as I take out the condition the column is returned in the results....

Comment: What do you retrieve now? @MikeD